# C/C++ macro expanding to argument, argument as string

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, stringification

I have many variables that are named the same as elements in an engineering specification document so the string version of the name is also useful.

I find myself using a macro like this a lot:

```
#define MACRO(a) a, #a
```

Typical usage is:

```
void someFunction(int a, const char *name);

someFunction(MACRO(meaningfully_named_variable));
```

My question is threefold:

- Is there a better way of doing this?
- Is a similar macro available in Boost or other libraries?
- If not, how could I refine and rename this to make it clear and useful?

**Edit**
I should have said that the above is a minimal example.  The function might have other parameters and the named entity might be a data member or perhaps even a function itself.

Another extension I'm considering for C++ is a class `NamedRef` that could receive the contents of the macro.

```
template <typename T>
struct NamedRef
{
    NamedRef(T *t, const char *name) : t(t), name(name) { }
    T *t;
    const char *name;
};

template <typename T>
NamedRef<T> namedRef(T &t, const char *name)
{
    return NamedRef<T>(&t, name);
}

#define WITH_NAME(a) a, #a

// more sophisticated usage example
void otherFunction(double, NamedRef<int>, bool);

otherFunction(0.0, namedRef(object.WITH_NAME(meaningful_member_name)), false);
```

Comment: All I'd do is pick a more descriptive name for the macro, e.g. `WITH_NAME()`.

Comment: Do what @MarkRansom suggested. My answer was a long way of saying "it's fine" and that Boost has a macro called `BOOST_STRINGIZE(X)`.

Answer (score 5):

You could take it a step further:

```
#define SOMEFUNCTION(a) somefunction(a, #a)
```

However, this is only useful if you call the same function alot. Otherwise, I don't think there is any better way than your example. Of course, you should change the name of the macro to something more meaningful though, like `ARGUMENTS` or something.

Comment: True, but if I have a lot of functions that receive `var, name` then I will have to write a lot of macros.

Comment: Not necessarily =>
`#define MACRO(funct_ptr, var) funct_ptr(var, #var)`
So you will need such many macro's how many different signature of function parameters you have...

Comment: OK, good thinking, but I think it's clearer to preserve the function syntax if possible, also function may have other args.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define someFunction(a)  if (1) stringized_someFunction((a), #a ); else (void)0
void stringized_someFunction(int a, const char* name);
```

The if (1) stuff wraps up the macro so that it won't mess (usually) with loops, branches, if statements, etc.

You would then call your function like so:

```
int r = 4;
someFunction(r);
```

You only really add one extra line for each "function declaration." If the C preprocessor allowed multiple steps you could wrap it all up into one, but alas, it doesn't.

I forgot because I hope it's obvious that you'd need to write your function:

```
void stringized_someFunction(int a, const char* name)
{
  // Do stuff here
}
```

Anyhow it should be a lot easier and prettier to read that way.

Comment: You forgot the semicolon in your macro definition before else. Also, I don`t think wrapping it in if(1) is necessary in this situation.

Comment: I know that you [need to wrap multi-statement macros](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Multi-statement_Macro) to prevent them from breaking code, but I don't understand the reason for single statements, if you could provide a counter-example it would be appreciated.

Comment: `if (1)` will cause problems if wrapped function needs to return a value.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to wrap a function call within an `if(1)` or `do{}while(0);` because you can't capture the result of the function call.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely to find that [XMACRO](http://drdobbs.com/184401387)s are useful for this kind of work.

Answer (score 0):

As Jesse answered,

you can write like this:

```
void function1(int a, const char* name)
{
    cout << "a: " << a << endl;
    cout << "name: " << name << endl;
}

void function2(double d, const char* name, const char *str)
{
    cout << "d: " << d << endl;
    cout << "name: " << name << endl;
    cout << "str: " << str << endl;
}

#define MACRO(functionName, a) functionName(a, #a)
#define MACRO2(functionName, a, ...) functionName(a, #a, __VA_ARGS__)

int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    MACRO(function1, a);
    double d = 10.5;
    MACRO2(function2, d, "Hello world");
    return 0;
}
```

If you have more arguments to pass, you can use MACRO2 that uses variable arguments. You will have to pass the function name accordingly.